# Hint for evaluate the complex integral

Tags: complex-analysis, contour-integration, complex-integration

Given question :

> Evaluate
>
> $$\int_C \left(z^2+1\right)^2\,\mathbb dz $$
>
> along the arc of the cycloid $x=a(\theta -\sin \theta),\,y=a(1-\cos
>  \theta)$ from the point where $\theta=0$ to the point where  $\theta
> =2\pi$

What should i do?

Should i substitute $z=x+iy,\,\mathbb dz=\mathbb dx+i \mathbb dy$, then just replace $x=a(\theta -\sin \theta),\,y=a(1-\cos \theta)$, then find the derivative of them w.r.t. $\theta$, and the integration is evaluated from $0$ to $2\pi$?

Or should i consider the "arc" word, which is i have to use arc length integral formula? I'm not sure.

Thanks. Anyway just let me do this by myself. I just need a hint.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The function that you are integrating is $(z^2+1)^2$, which has a primitive: $F(z)=\frac{z^5}5+\frac{2z^3}3+z$. So,$$\int_C(z^2+1)^2\,\mathrm dz=F(2\pi a)-F(0).$$

Comment: So in this case, i have to ignore the information about $x$ and $y$? Considering it's integrated w.r.t $z$?

Comment: I did **not** ignore it. I used that fact that $x(0)=y(0)=y(2\pi)=0$ and that $x(2\pi)=2\pi a$.

Comment: Just one quick question. What i got from you, the result is $$\begin{align}F(z_1)-F(z_2)&=F(x_1(2\pi)+i y_1(\pi))-F(x_2(2\pi)+i y_2(\pi))\\ &=F(2\pi a)-F(0)\end{align}$$  am i right?

Comment: Yes, that is correct.